# Uploading image to Azure blob storage returns text

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage, form-data

I'm trying to upload an image on Azure blob storage using RestAPI with passing a token. It works on postman. I am able to fetch the uploaded image correctly. Uploading from Angular also works but when I try fetching what I uploaded I get some text instead of the image. Below is an example if the text.
Below text is part of the entire text which I receive.

------WebKitFormBoundaryCCltz7yE7w2qTIUX Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="img3 - Copy - Copy.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg ����JFIF���ICC_PROFILE�0mntrRGB XYZ acsp���- desc�$rXYZgXYZ(bXYZ<�wtptPrTRCd(gTRCd(bTRCd(cprt�No᧟Js=٠+3Y��n���:�^�H @O����:�^�HJ�������vh %Y�����o|�@'7��ό�I��w�o��x���R��gx���}`)��f�n����R��vh*��w���No᧟f�hRr������:�p�U'+]��No᧟���y�)Y�������h�9��� /��/���)��o|�@*����)Y��� �r��@*�����_?O���o|�@2S����g/_�%9^�� ?���i��R��gx��Y����Vf�4��{�@,���gx�9z� I��w�XJs=٠���y�:�^�H @O���y�U'+]�J�����+��Js=٠+3Y��Nf�4����K����Vf�4��k�� Vf�4|���O>0��W���u|�>�� )3w���Y��� /���Y^������)9Z�� �����*S���%Y^�� �r��@'7��ό)YZ�������?

Code I used to upload image

```
uploadFile(file: any, securedUrl: string){
    this.securedUrl = securedUrl;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);
      formData.append('fileName', "file123");
      var requestData = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        })
      };
      this.http.put(securedUrl, formData, httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
      };


  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because Azure Storage does not support `multipart/form-data`. What you have to do is read the contents of your image file as binary data and upload that directly.

Your code would be something like (untested code):

```
uploadFile(file: any, securedUrl: string){
    this.securedUrl = securedUrl;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      var requestData = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        })
      };
      this.http.put(securedUrl, requestData, httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    };


  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav for the response. It worked as expected.
I would like to add what I changed in my code from your response. Simply passing the file that I choose to upload in put request

uploadFile(file: any, securedUrl: string){
   .......
      this.http.put(securedUrl, file, httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

Answer (score 1):

Below is updated code after Gaurav's suggestion. Second paramerter (formData) is replaced with the binary file which is selected to upload.

```
uploadFile(file: any, securedUrl: string){
this.securedUrl = securedUrl;
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (e: any) => {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
    })
  };
  this.http.put(securedUrl, file, httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
};
```

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).