# Image Cant Upload In Form-data format In Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, postman, azure-blob-storage, form-data

I'm trying to upload an image in form-data format through Postman to store in Azure Blob storage, postman gives response 200 but it cannot store in Azure Blob storage.

(Note: I want to store the image in form-data, not in binary data because our frontend team want the image in form-data format)

How do I solve it?
[image]

And This is the Blob storage Screenshot.
[image]

Comment: you are welcome to comment and accept answer

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know blob storage does not support `multipart/form-data`, please check Microsoft doc regarding [Azure Storage supports three types of blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction#blobs).

With that said, there are a similar questions in stack overflow [Uploading image to Azure blob storage returns text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75971251/uploading-image-to-azure-blob-storage-returns-text) that might give you some inspiration.