# Efficient Large File Upload(500GB) to Azure Blob Storage from ReactJS UI with FastAPI/Flask Backend

Tags: python, reactjs, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, large-file-upload

I'm working on a project where I need to upload very large files (approximately 500GB) from a ReactJS front-end to Azure Blob Storage, using a Python-based FastAPI or Flask backend. My goal is to optimize the upload process to make it as efficient as possible.

I'm aware that chunking the file and making multiple calls to the backend is a common approach for large file uploads, but it can be time-consuming, especially given the large file size.

I'd like to achieve the following:

1. Upload the 500GB file in less than 20 minutes.
2. Take into account a stable internet connection with a speed of around 100Mbps.

What are the best practices and tools I should consider to achieve this goal efficiently? Are there any specific libraries or methods that can help with optimizing the upload process? Additionally, are there any configuration or settings I should be aware of in Azure Blob Storage for such large uploads?

I'm open to any suggestions or recommendations to streamline this large file upload process effectively. Thank you for your insights!

Comment: `500 * 1024 / (100 / 8) / 60 / 60 = 11.3(7)` hrs of uploading a 500GB file with 100Mb/s connection

Comment: Did you try to run a compression of the original files before sending them?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately compression is not allowed. I can do parallel execution to achieve efficient way but reading from UI also one more challenging aspect!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below method to improve your blob upload performance:-

File upload form with an input field for selecting a file and a button to trigger the upload.
Sample code for a combination of a FastAPI backend and a React frontend for uploading to Azure Blob Storage.

**React frontend:**

File upload form with an input field for selecting a file and a button to trigger the upload.

```js
function  App()  {

const  [selectedFile,  setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

  

const  handleFileChange = (event)  =>  {

setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);

};

  

const  handleFileUpload = async  ()  =>  {

const  formData = new  FormData();

formData.append('file',  selectedFile);

  

try  {

const  response = await  axios.post('http://localhost:8000/upload/',  formData,  {

headers:  {

'Content-Type':  'multipart/form-data',

},

});

console.log(response.data);

}  catch (error) {

console.error('File upload failed:',  error);

}

};

  

return (

<div>

<h1>File Upload</h1>

<input  type="file"  onChange={handleFileChange}  />

<button  onClick={handleFileUpload}>Upload File</button>

</div>

);

}
```

[image]

**FastAPI Backend:**

The `/upload/` endpoint allows the client to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage. It accepts a file upload using the `UploadFile` type.

```py
app = FastAPI()

# Allow CORS for your front-end application
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["http://localhost:3000"],  # Update with your front-end URL
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

# Initialize the Azure Blob Storage client
azure_blob_service = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("BlodConnectionString")

# Function to check the connection to Azure Blob Storage
def is_azure_connected():
    try:
        azure_blob_service.get_service_properties()
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

@app.post("/upload/")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile):
    container_client = azure_blob_service.get_container_client("ContainerName")

    try:
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file.filename)

        # Upload the file in chunks
        with file.file as f:
            chunk_size = 500 * 1024 * 1024  
            total_length = 0
            chunks = []
            while True:
                chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                chunks.append(chunk)
                total_length += len(chunk)

            for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
                blob_client.upload_blob(data=chunk, blob_type=BlobType.BlockBlob, length=total_length)

        # Fetch the blob properties to get the file size
        blob_properties = blob_client.get_blob_properties()
        file_size = blob_properties['size']

        message = f"File uploaded successfully. File size: {file_size} bytes"
        print("File uploaded")
    except Exception as e:
        message = "File upload failed"
        print(f"File upload failed: {str(e)}")

    response_data = {"message": message}

    return JSONResponse(content=response_data)

@app.get("/list_files/")
async def list_files():
    container_client = azure_blob_service.get_container_client("sampathpujari")
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()

    file_list = [{"file_name": blob.name, "file_size": blob.size} for blob in blob_list]

    return JSONResponse(content=file_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if is_azure_connected():
        print("Connected to Azure Blob Storage")
    else:
        print("Connection to Azure Blob Storage failed")
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Much! Sampath for your time and efforts.

Here I am mostly looking at time complexity, i have tried similar logics but time is taking more.
I will try this and capture the time complexity, based on that will take a call.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve a similar problem, the problem is that azure does not allow `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` to upload files, try this
StackOverflow Answers

1. [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75971251/uploading-image-to-azure-blob-storage-returns-text)
2. [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355288/upload-filesusing-azure-blob-storage-sdk)