# Can't play this video. VideoView Android after retrieve back video from Azure Blob

Tags: android, video, azure-blob-storage

I am recording video using CameraX then store it locally like this

```
val contentValues = ContentValues()
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")

MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(contentResolver, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI).setContentValues(contentValues).build()
```

I am able to play this video using VideoView

```
val videoUri = videoRecordEvent.outputResults.outputUri
val mediaController = MediaController(this, false)

mediaController.setAnchorView(binding.videoView)
binding.videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
binding.videoView.requestFocus()
binding.videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri))
binding.videoView.start()
```

Then I do send this video into server where I move this video into Azure Blob Container.
I am sending video using Multipart with Retrofit:

```
val videoRequestBody = File(videoFile).asRequestBody("video/mp4".toMediaTypeOrNull())
videoPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", videoFile.toString(), videoRequestBody)
```

At server site I retrieve video using IFormFile interface then I save it into blob

```
var value = (await formFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream)).ToArray();
await containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(blobName, new BinaryData(value));
```

Then after I want to play this video fetching it from blob url I get error message

> Can't play this video.

with the error

> -2147483648

I read it is connected with encoding stuff. I checked blob`s content type and it was set as **application/octet-stream**. I have changed it into **video/mp4** the same mime type as I do save in Android device before sent.

The same blob is working for iOS devices.

What do I miss?

Comment: Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355288/upload-filesusing-azure-blob-storage-sdk.

Comment: Can I give C# code to upload the Video with content-type?

Comment: @miechooy **(1)** _"I want to play this video fetching it from blob url"_ show us what you mean. Save the blob as a file and upload it somewhere then give us a link to check. **(2)** It's possible the problem is that your MP4 data has its metadata at the back. It should still work if the blob has ALL the bytes of the video file downloaded into it (get ALL bytes from server before playing).